# Find the integral $\int \:x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \left(1+x^{\frac{1}{4}}\right)^{-10} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Help me find the integral. I think we have to somehow replace apply.

$$\int \:x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \left(1+x^{\frac{1}{4}}\right)^{-10} dx =\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x} (1+x^{\frac{1}{4}})^{10}} dx $$

Comment: set $t=\sqrt[4]{x}$

Comment: Could you at least show an attempt, or motivation for computing this integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just perform the change of variable $x=u^4$, to get
$$
\begin{align}
\int \:x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \left(1+x^{\frac{1}{4}}\right)^{-10} dx&=4\int \:u^{-2}\cdot \left(1+u\right)^{-10} u^3du\\\\
&=4\int \frac{1}{(1+u)^9} du-4\int  \frac{1}{(1+u)^{10}}du\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{2 (1+u)^8}+\frac{4}{9 (1+u)^9}+C\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{2 \left(1+x^{1/4}\right)^9}+\frac{4}{9 \left(1+x^{1/4}\right)^9}+C.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: this is my substitution in the comment

Comment: Thank you all, you helped me a lot

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I did not see it.

Comment: @andre1 You are welcome!

Comment: hm, it is $t=\sqrt[4]{x}$ and now?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: is there a problem? An equivalent substitution was used here. If you wanted to get reputation for it, you should have written an answer. Just because a substitution is given in a comment should not prevent others from using a similar one in an answer. That might prevent a question from ever being answered.

Comment: yes ok that is clear for me but posters use that $t=\sqrt[4]{x}$ and my answer is: there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $u = 1 + x^{1/4}$, then $du = (1/4)x^{-3/4}dx$.  This becomes a helpful substitution if you replace $x^{-1/2}$ with $x^{-3/4}x^{1/4} = x^{-3/4}(u-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

let $$x=u^4$$
$$dx=4u^3 du$$
$$\int \frac{4u^3 du}{u^2(1+u)^{10}}=\int (\frac{4}{(u+1)^9}-\frac{4}{(u+1)^{10}})du$$